# save hive or hbase table in hdinsight

Tags: hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I am new to hdinsight. On a normal in-house cluster I could create a new table and place it in an existing schema or create a new schema to retrieve it later. I can do similar methods if I create an hbase table.

If I create a table in Hive or a table in base in Hdinsight, what do I have to do before I shut down to be able to query the table I just created.

I've searched the docs, but have missed the location of the details for this procedure. I don't want to create a sql database.

Answer (score 0):

In HDInsight data is stored in Azure/Blob or Azure Data lake store and Metastore is in Azure SQL DB. If you choose your own Metastore , your hive schemas could persist beyond the lifecycle of the cluster. More here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2017/03/24/hive-metastore-in-hdinsight-tips-tricks-best-practices/